# Access Ajax data in python

Tags: python, ajax, json, cgi, sys

I am newbie in python and  am using **Python** to get the **request from AJAX calls** but I am getting the code of python as it is inside the **AJAX output** which I don't want.

**AJAX Code :**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "hello.py",
        datatype : "json",
        data: { name: "nitin"}
      })
      .done(function(msg) {
           console.log(msg);
           $("div").html("Data : "+msg)
});
```

**Python Code :**

```
import sys
import cgi

sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: application/json")
sys.stdout.write("\n") 
sys.stdout.write("\n")

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

sys.stdout.write(json.dumps({ 'data': form.getvalue('name')}))
```

**Output :** `Data : import sys import cgi sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: application/json") sys.stdout.write("\n") sys.stdout.write("\n") form = cgi.FieldStorage() sys.stdout.write(json.dumps({ 'data': form.getvalue('name')}))`

**Expected Output should be :**

```
Data : Content-Type: application/json

nitin
```

Comment: Have you configured your web server to treat Python fires as cgi? And why are you using cgi in the first place?

Comment: Sorry sir.. I don't have any idea **configure web server to treat Python fires as cgi**. Didn't get **why are you using cgi in the first place?**.

Comment: I have added `Options +ExecCGI   AddHandler cgi-script .py` these line in **.htaccess** file in my local web server(apache). After adding this, **python script is now executable** but unable to get response of python in the **AJAX**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below 2 lines inside **.htaccess** file under **/home/*/public_html**.

```
Options +ExecCGI 
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

**Python code** should be like that :

```
import sys
import cgi
sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
sys.stdout.write("\n") 
sys.stdout.write("\n")
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
name = form.getvalue('name')
print name
```

Because content-type is of application/x-www-form-urlencoded not application/json. We are getting form values. If want to see the type of content simply **`print form.headers`**.

Answer (score 1):

is your python script marked as executable? see [this](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html#common-problems-with-cgi-scripts) -

"The Python script is not marked as executable. When CGI scripts are not executable most web servers will let the user download it, instead of running it and sending the output to the user. For CGI scripts to run properly on Unix-like operating systems, the +x bit needs to be set. Using chmod a+x your_script.py may solve this problem."

there is also a sample to test if your server supports CGI -

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html#simple-script-for-testing-cgi

Comment: yes. my python script is marked as executable. Before running it, I had done chmod +x /path-to-localhost/hello.py. Any other help. plz

Comment: I have added `Options +ExecCGI   AddHandler cgi-script .py` these line in **.htaccess** file in my local web server(apache). After adding this, **python script is now executable** but unable to get response of python in the **AJAX**.